# How to implement remove handler in C++ event

Tags: c++, events, delegates, bind

I have an Event class. In `AddHandler(thisPtr, callback)` I use `tr1::bind` on `thisPtr` and `callback` and eventually I have a list:

```
typedef std::tr1::function<void( int& )> CallbackFunction;
std::list< CallbackFunction > m_handlers;
```

But how can I implement a remove handler method if `tr1::function` is non-comparable?

Should I keep a map from object pointers and callbacks to `tr1::function` and remove the one having equal object pointer and callback pointer to the arguments in `RemoveHandler`? Is this a safe approach?

Comment: Perhaps you should just return the iterator of the inserted object. Also, check Boost.Signals2, libsigc++, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using an std::list, which never invalidates iterators, as long as the element stays in the container, you can use an iterator to keep track of the functions you insert.  Example:

```
typedef std::list<CallbackFunction> func_list;
typedef typename func_list::iterator func_it;
func_it Insert(func_list & l, Callback c)
{
    l.insert(l.begin(), c);
    return l.begin();
}
```

Now, you can call that function to insert a callback, and it will return an iterator to it, which you can use to remove it, like this:

```
func_it it = Insert(l, c);
l.erase(it);
```

Comment: I don't want users to save iterators. How do I look up the correct iterator given `RemoveHandler(thisPtr, memberPtr)`?

Comment: @Leo: You need to have some means by which you can identify the `std::function`.  And as you are aware, you cannot compare the functions themselves.  You could store the functions in a pair with some comparable value(perhaps in a map), like an integer, then look up the function by that value.  The user will still need to store that value in order to identify the function later.  If that's not acceptable, I cannot think of a solution that will help you.

Comment: Why should the user remember anything besides his own this pointer and member function (like in C#)? Can I use these 2 values as the comparable?